# determining the winner in a rock paper scissor game

Tags: java, methods

in this rock paper scissor game i need an different method to determine winner. when i run my program the rest runs smoothly but i wont display a winner. i think their might be a logical error in my code.

```
public static void determineWinner(String userLower, String comp) {

      String user = userLower;
      String computer = comp;

      if(user.equals(computer)) {
            System.out.println("It's a tie!");
      } else if(user.equals("rock")) {
            if(computer.equals("scissors")) {
                  System.out.println("You win!");
            }
      } else if(computer.equals("rock")) {
            if(user.equals("scissors")) {
                  System.out.println("You lose!");
            }
      } else if(user.equals("scissors")) {
            if(computer.equals("paper")){
                  System.out.println("You win!");
            }
      } else if(computer.equals("scissors")) {
            if(user.equals("paper")) {
                  System.out.println("You lose");
            }
      } else if(user.equals("paper")) {
            if(computer.equals("rock")) {
                  System.out.println("You Win!");
            }
      } else if(computer.equals("paper")) {
            if(user.equals("rock")) {
                  System.out.println("You lose!");
            }    
      }
```

Comment: Use statements like this `else if(computer.equals("scissors") && user.equals("paper"))`

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you are testing every possible combination (with the exception of a tie). With rock-paper-scissors, you have 9 different outcomes, and 3 of them are ties so there are 6 more left.

Now imagine you have to do this for the 21st century variant "rock-paper-scissors-lizard-Spock": 25 different outcomes. That's a long list of `if else`s.

However: all possible outcomes can be stored into a table, and that table can be as small (or large) as you want. This table is for RPSLS (can't find one for RPS), but the principle is the same:

[image: rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock winners]

You pick your choice vertically and the computer's horizontally; then, the number on the left is points for you (obviously, 1 is for Win, -1 is Lose) and the number on the right is the opponent.

---

(Edit) Here is the table for Rock-Paper-Scissors. You don't need two elements per combination, the other one is always the opposite of what's shown. The table shows Winner in the columns, Loser in the rows.

```
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
|          | Rock  | Paper |Scissors|
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
| Rock     |   0   |   1   |   -1   |
| Paper    |  -1   |   0   |    1   |
| Scissors |   1   |  -1   |    0   |
+----------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check 3 cases for the user: he has rock, paper or scissors. For each action the computer will have 2 options (cause the tie is already handled) see my code below

```
     if(user.equals(computer)){
                System.out.println("It's a tie!");


            }
            else if(user.equals("rock")){
                if(computer.equals("scissors")){
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                else if (computer.equals("paper"){
                    System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                }


                }
            }else if(user.equals("scissors")){
                if(computer.equals("paper")){
                    System.out.println("You win!");
                else if (computer.equals("rock"){
                    System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                }


                }
            }else if(user.equals("paper")){
                if(computer.equals("rock")){
                    System.out.println("You Win!");

                }
                else if (computer.equals("scissors"){
                    System.out.println("Computer wins!");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try evalutating without `else if` statements and use simple `if` statements.

For example, lets say `user="rock"` and `computer!="scissors"`, then the following first `else if` statement is true, but the second `if` statement is false. Because the next `else if` statement is related to the first `else if` (which was true), it doesnt get executed.

```
                 else if(user.equals("rock")){
                    if(computer.equals("scissors")){
                        System.out.println("You win!");


                    }
                }else if(computer.equals("rock")){
                    if(user.equals("scissors")){
                        System.out.println("You lose!");


                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `else if` it is exclusive. So for example:

```
else if (user.equals("rock")){
   if (computer.equals("scissors")) {
      System.out.println("You win!");
   }
}
```

Imagine the user chose `"rock"` but the computer chose `"paper"`. Then the if / else construct will exit without a winner printed.

You need to re-think your logic!

Answer (score 0):

You need `else` clauses to cover all scenarios:

```
 } else if(user.equals("rock")) {
     if(computer.equals("scissors")) {
         System.out.println("You win!");
     } // There is no logic to handle user = "rock", computer != "sicssors"
 } else if ...
```

Did you perhaps intend to write this instead?

```
 } else if(user.equals("rock") && computer.equals("scissors")) {
     System.out.println("You win!");
 } else if ...
```

You could also assign numbers to the different items and perform a simple math operation to determine the winner:

```
Map<String, int> map = new HashMap<String, int>();
map.put("rock", 1);
map.put("paper", 2);
map.put("scissors", 3);

int user = map.get(userLower);
int computer = map.get(comp) % 3;

if(user %3 == computer) {
    System.out.println("It's a tie!");
} else if(user == computer-1) {
    System.out.println("You win!");
} else {
    System.out.println("You lose!");
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the `-` sign in the `else if` should be a `+`.

Comment: Why are you using the `%` operator here?

Comment: @Omicron: By looking at the remainder, I'm having `1,2,3` for hand A become `1,2,0` for hand B, thus creating the a pattern where the winning hand is always one where `A == B-1`. If A is `2 (paper)` then B has to be `1 (rock)`. If A is `1 (rock)` then B has to be `0 (scissors)`. This only allows me to test for `A beats B`. To test for equality, I have to perform the same operation at hand A, or test before I apply the operation to hand B.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if (user.equals (computer)) {
    System.out.println ("It's a tie!");
} else if (user.equals ("rock")) {
    if (computer.equals ("scissors")) {
    System.out.println ("You win!");
    } else if (computer.equals ("paper")) {
    System.out.println ("You lose!");
    }
} else if (user.equals ("scissors")) {
    if (computer.equals ("rock")) {
    System.out.println ("You lose!");
    } else if (computer.equals ("paper")) {
    System.out.println ("You win!");
    }
} else if (user.equals ("paper")) {
    if (computer.equals ("rock")) {
    System.out.println ("You win!");
    } else if (computer.equals ("scissors")) {
    System.out.println ("You lose!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not check both inputs at the first if level.
This should work for you.

```
public static void determineWinner(String userLower, String comp) {
     String user = userLower;
     String computer = comp;

if(user.equals(computer)){
    System.out.println("It's a tie!");
}
else if(user.equals("rock")){
    if(computer.equals("scissors") || computer.equals("paper")){
        System.out.println("You win!");
    }
}else if(user.equals("scissors")){
    if(computer.equals("paper")){
        System.out.println("You win!");
    }else if(computer.equals("rock")){
        System.out.println("You lose!");
    }
}else if(user.equals("paper")){
    if(computer.equals("rock")){
        System.out.println("You Win!");
    }else if(computer.equals("scissor")){
        System.out.println("You lose!");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Lets define score for both players actions:

```
Player + S is 1
Player + P is 2
Player + R is 4

//same actions of computer yeld negative score with same amounts

if (player.score() + AI.score() == 0)
   return tie(); // both players did same action

if (player.score() + AI.score() == 1)
//S + P combination we need to check who plays S
   return player.score() == 1 ? win() : lose()

if (player.score() + AI.score() == 2)
//P + R combination same check here
   return player.score() == 2 ? win() : lose()

if (player.score() + AI.score() == 3)
//S + R combination same check here
   return player.score() == 4 ? win() : lose()
```

with ENUM or switchcase this can be done ever more optimal with some checks skipped completely

add

```
int [] scoretable = {1, 2, 4,
                    -2,-4,-1};
//                   R  S  P

//lose condition zero result
// R+P 1-1  = 0
// P+S 4-4  = 0
// S+R 2-2  = 0

//all other conditions are win or tie, tie checked before score calculated
```

allows to check for win in single line action.